May I say that if $(M,d)$ is a metric space and $K \subseteq M$ is closed, then $K$ dist(a) is a minimum (and vice versa)?
I am slightly stuck on the proof of the following proposition: is it ok to look at the cases $K$ is open and $K$ is closed seperately, and if so, does it work in my favour as I claim?

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space and $\emptyset \neq K\subseteq M$. Define \begin{equation}
\text { dist : } M \rightarrow \mathbb{R},\\x \mapsto \inf \{d(x, y) \mid y \in K\}
\end{equation}
Show that for all $a, b \in M$ it is true that \begin{equation}
|\operatorname{dist}(a)-\operatorname{dist}(b)| \leq d(a, b).
\end{equation}

This is how I proceeded: Assume $\operatorname{dist}(a) - \operatorname{dist}(b)\geq 0$. We consider the cases $K$ is open and $K$ is closed separately.
If $K$ is open, then the set $\{ d(a,x)\mid x \in K\}$ does not have a minimum (Is this step legit?). As such we may write $\operatorname{dist}(a)< d(a,x) $ for all $x \in K$. It follows that $$\operatorname{dist}(a)-\operatorname{dist}(b)< d(a,x)-\operatorname{dist}(b) \leq d(a,b) + d(b,x) -\operatorname{dist}(b).$$
The difference $d(b,x) -\operatorname{dist}(b)$ is always non-negative, but gets infinitely small. As such, we have that for all $\delta>0$,
$$\operatorname{dist}(a)-\operatorname{dist}(b)< d(a,b) + \delta$$
and as such $\operatorname{dist}(a)-\operatorname{dist}(b) \leq d(a,b)$ (this follows from a previous exercise).
Now let $K$ be closed. Then $\operatorname{dist}(a) = \min \{d(a,x)\mid x \in K\}$ and $\operatorname{dist}(b) = \min \{d(b,x)\mid x \in K\}$ (again: legit?). As such, we have $\operatorname{dist}(a)\leq d(a,x) $ for all $x \in K$. It follows that $$\operatorname{dist}(a)-\operatorname{dist}(b)\leq d(a,x)-\operatorname{dist}(b) \leq d(a,b) + d(b,x) -\operatorname{dist}(b).$$ Choose $x\in K$ in such a way that $d(b,x) = \operatorname{dist}(b)$. Then we have $\operatorname{dist}(a)-\operatorname{dist}(b) \leq d(a,b)$, as needed.

None of these are legit, I'm afraid. There are sets that are neither open nor closed, so without further argument, your argument is not general. It's also not true that the infimum is not achieved for all open $K$, nor is it achieved for every closed $K$ (though, it would be achieved for compact $K$). Since you only seem to use openness/closedness to conclude whether the infimum is achieved or not, why not just assume the infimum is achieved or not directly? One or the other of these must be true.

I read only the first two lines of the question, stopping after "look at the cases $K$ is open and $K$ is closed separately." What if $K$ is neither open nor closed?

@Theo Bendit: Yes, originally I wanted to do exactly that. The problem I encountered was the following: assume dist $(a)$ is the minimum of the set ${d(a, x) \mid x \in K}$ but the set ${d(b, x) \mid x \in K}$ does not have a minimum. Then we have $\operatorname{dist}(a)-\operatorname{dist}(b) \leq d(a, b)+d(b, x)-\operatorname{dist}(b)$, but cannot choose $x \in K$ such that the difference $d(b, x)-\operatorname{dist}(b)=0$. We also cannot use the property I applied in the other case, as we have $\leq$, not $<.-$

@klonedrekt I understand. I would abandon the dichotomy entirely then. But the idea of using your previous exercise still works. Note that $d(a, x) \le d(a, b) + d(b, x)$ for all $x \in K$. If you suppose $\delta > 0$ is arbitrary, then there will always exist $x \in X$ such that $d(b, x) < \operatorname{dist}(b) + \delta$ (which is true, regardless of whether the infimum is achieved). See if you can complete the proof from here.

@TheoBendit Cheers, got it now. Thank you for your help.
